# Show image based on chosen radio input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As the title says, how to make this in VueJS

There is a start point https://jsbin.com/tomevukisa/edit?html,js,output

I guess it's something about index matching because I did something similar with jQuery in this way

```
  $('.Colors > li').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('.Items > li.active').fadeOut(200, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active').parent('ul').children('li').eq(i).fadeIn(100).addClass('active');
    });
  });
```

But now it's about VueJS only.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your actual question? What issue are you having?

Comment: @EvanKnowles I need some guide (tips) how to show image based on choosen radio input.They should match by index.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Radio

Comment: `v-model` on the radio buttons, several `v-if`s based on the resulting value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a `value` for the radio buttons. Since you want to compare based on `$index`, that's the value to set.

```
<input type="radio" name="color" value="{{$index}}" v-model="picker">
```

To control whether something displays, use the [`v-show` binding](https://vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#v-show):

```
v-show="+$index === +picker"
```

I use unary `+` to ensure that both are numeric.

```js
new Vue({
  
  el: 'body',
  
  data: {
    picker: 1,
    images: [
      {img_src: 'http://cl.jroo.me/z3/q/R/R/d/a.aaa-Unique-Nature-Beautiful-smal.jpg'},
      {img_src: 'http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v477/n7365/images/477415a-f1.2.jpg'},
      {img_src: 'http://scr.templatemonster.com/35100/35151_gall_nature_small_3.jpg'}
    ],
    colors: [
      {id: 1, name: 'Black'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Red'},
      {id: 3, name: 'Green'}
    ]
  }
  
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li img {
  width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<ul class="Items">
    <li v-for="image in images">
      <img v-show="+$index === +picker" :src="image.img_src" >
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul class="Colors">
    <li v-for="color in colors">
      <input type="radio" name="color" value="{{$index}}" v-model="picker">
      <span>{{ color.name }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```